# Polymer 1.0: <paper-button> for authentication buttons (register, sign-up, login, sign-in, etc.)?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en) for Polymer 1.0 with [Yeoman scaffolding](http://yeoman.io).

I want to add `sign up` and `login` buttons in the upper right corner of the top, main horizontal toolbar (which is a `<paper-toolbar>` element). When the user clicks one of these buttons, the app should route them to the appropriate page/form or, alternatively, a modal or dialog.

I want the styling of (or similar to) the `<paper-button>` elements because I want to use the `:hover` effect.

What is the recommended "Polymer 1.0 way" to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't the Paper-icon-button be what you're looking for? https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-icon-button

Comment: What's wrong with just using `paper-button` then? Also, you can apply any styling to any element with `:hover` in css. Could you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a custom element with all the relevant styles, templates and scripts to express the UX.